# rendering MUI components in jsdom with react testing library during mocha test causes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mocha.js, react-testing-library

Because `enzyme` is not being maintained and does not support react 18+, I am trying to migrate 1750+ existing unit tests to run with `react-testing-library` + `global-jsdom`, so life can go on and our app can keep running latest version of react. All our tests were written using; `mocha`, `chai`, `enzyme` - and I want to migrate as simply as possible. In other words I am under no circumstacens going to rewrite 1750+ test in a completely new framework like `jest`.

I'm trying to follow an [example](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library#basic-example) of using `react-testing-library` to unit test react components. If I use simple elements like `'div'` or `'input'` when using `React.createElement` it works just fine, but when I use material UI components, I get an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'registered')
> at C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules@emotion\styled\base\dist\emotion-styled-base.cjs.dev.js:143:53
>
> The above error occurred in the <Styled(div)> component:
>
> ```
> at C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\@emotion\react\dist\emotion-element-b63ca7c6.cjs.dev.js:43:23
> at Box (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\node_modules\@mui\system\createBox.js:29:41)
> at DummyComponent (C:\Users\user\Documents\project\act-app\src\component\page\dummyComponent.js:2:346)
> ```
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries.
> The stacktrace is not accurate, but it fails where I try to do `h(Box, {},...)` (create the mui element).

This is the `dummyComponent.js` that I am trying to render:

```
const { Box } = require('@mui/material');
const React = require('react');
const h = React.createElement;

const DummyComponent = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    h(Box, {},
      h('label', { htmlFor: 'toggle' }, 'Show/Hide'),
      h('input', { id: 'toggle', type: 'checkbox', onChange: (e) => setShowChild(e.target.checked), checked: showChild }),
      showChild && children)
  );
};

module.exports = DummyComponent;
```

This is the mocha unit test:

```
const React = require('react');
const { render, fireEvent } = require('@testing-library/react');
const h = React.createElement;

const DummyComponent = require('./dummyComponent');

describe('pageCenter', function () {
  before(function () {
    this.jsdom = require('global-jsdom')();
  });

  after(function () {
    this.jsdom();
  });

  it('should render', function () {
    const w = render(h(DummyComponent, {}, 'Hi!'));
    w.queryAllByText('Hi!').should.have.length(0);
    fireEvent.click(w.getByLabelText('Show/Hide'));
    w.queryAllByText('Hi!').should.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

It feels like I am missing some context to allow MUI components to be rendered, but I can't seem to figure out what, or if this is actually the case. There are not too many google results on this particular error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the MUI librarie dependencies I saw they were using **@emotion/react** and **@emotion/styled** for some rendering processes, it looks like a problem with **MUI v5** where they change the cache object and accidentally remove the cache object provided by **@emotion/react**, this leads to the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'registered' of undefined` cause they are not adding the `cache.registered` in the new cache.

Solution: I solved the issue just by wrapping my component in @emotion/react provider ({my component}). You can try following this example provided by @emotion.react: https://emotion.sh/docs/cache-provider

Also make sure to have proper dependencies from @emotion/react by runnin:
`npm install --save @emotion/react` or `yarn add @emotion/react`

this is how your code should look:

This is the dummyComponent.js in a more familiar JSX syntax:

```
const React = require('react');
const { Box } = require('@mui/material');

const DummyComponent = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const [showChild, setShowChild] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Box>
      <label htmlFor="toggle">Show/Hide</label>
      <input
        id="toggle"
        type="checkbox"
        onChange={(e) => setShowChild(e.target.checked)}
        checked={showChild}
      />
      {showChild && children}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default DummyComponent;
```

This is the mocha unit test:

```
const React = require('react');
const { expect } = require('chai');
const { render, fireEvent } = require('@testing-library/react');
const createCache = require("@emotion/cache");

const DummyComponent = require('./dummyComponent');

describe('pageCenter', function () {
  before(function () {
    this.jsdom = require('global-jsdom')();
  });

  after(function () {
    this.jsdom();
  });
  
  const myCache = createCache({
   key: 'my-prefix-key'
  });

  it('should render', function () {
    const { queryAllByText, getByLabelText } = render(
      <CacheProvider value={myCache}>          
        <DummyComponent>Hi!</DummyComponent>
      </CacheProvider>
    );

    expect(queryAllByText('Hi!')).should.have.length(0);
    fireEvent.click(getByLabelText('Show/Hide'));
    expect(queryAllByText('Hi!')).should.have.length(1);
  });
});
```

Notice that I'm also using some JSX syntax in the test case and `const { expect } = require('chai');` this allows me to use `should` and chain other functions from **chai**.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, this is what I ended up doing as well - I completely forgot about this question, so thank you for brining a solution to it!